# Android Glide - Cannot recycle a resource that has already been recycled

Tags: android, android-glide, illegalstateexception, recycle

I have a list of objects the user can create and delete on runtime and each object is assigned an icon. When I do multiple add/delete operations on these objects at some point I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot recycle a resource that has already been recycled
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineResource.recycle(EngineResource.java:71)
at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ResourceRecycler$ResourceRecyclerCallback.handleMessage(ResourceRecycler.java:37)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

I perform no recycle operations on my own and I do not make any calls to Glide bitmap pool. My custom Glide model is the following class

```
public class MyGlideInput {

    private String packageName, apkFilePath, iconResName;

    public MyGlideInput() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        if(obj == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(!(obj instanceof MyGlideInput)){
            return false;
        }
        MyGlideInput input = (MyGlideInput) obj;
        return stringsEqual(packageName, input.packageName ) && stringsEqual(apkFilePath, input.apkFilePath)
                && stringsEqual(iconResName, input.iconResName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (apkFilePath+packageName+iconResName+"").hashCode();
    }

    public boolean stringsEqual(String a, String b){
        return a != null && a.equals(b);
    }

}
```

on RecyclerView adapter class in bindViewHolder I do:

```
GlideInput glideInput = new GlideInput().setDrawableResName(iconResName);
GlideApp.with(img).load(glideInput).dontAnimate().error(R.drawable.warning).into(img);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: any solution???

Comment: @zeroDivider unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen until now, this error appears mostly because of transformations if you have any. I had some recycling in transform method even though it's stated that developers should not do it by themselves in their custom transformations. Also, you should be really careful in `RecycleView`.

Can you provide us with more of code, e.g. some transformations that you use or whatever you think it can have some bad impact?